# drawing graphics transparency

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics

I want to anti-alias a circle drawn inside my custom button (`FlatStyle` set to `Flat`), but the `SmoothingMode.AntiAlias` doesn't work in my case.

Here's my code inside `OnPaint`:

```
    Dim GP As New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
    Dim newRectangle As Rectangle = ClientRectangle

    ' decrease the size of the rectangle to remove the border
    newRectangle.Inflate(-1, -1)

    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    GP.AddEllipse(newRectangle)
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Transparent, GP)

    Me.Region = New Region(GP)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
```

So is it possible to draw within a button and antialias the shapes inside of it?

Comment: try also setting `InterpolationMode = HighQualityBicubic` and  `CompositingQuality = HighQuality`.  you might want to explain what "doesn't work" means so we know what needs to be fixed.

Comment: tried also like that. and nothing happens, it seems they don't have effect. e.g the SmoothingMode set to SmoothingMode.AntiAlias it's exactly like SmoothingMode.Default.

Comment: Regions cannot be anti-aliased.  Anti-aliasing can only work with a known background, by definition is always unknown for a window since you cannot know what is behind that window. It constantly changes.  Never set a form's Region property in OnPaint() btw, it belongs in the constructor.

Comment: And you can draw an ellipse much easier using `e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Transparent, newRectangle)`

Comment: If i don't draw the ellipse with the code i posted, and i draw it with DrawEllipse I cannot get the true transparent background out of the circle. Do you know why? Can you post a sample code with transparent background? Much appreciated tour help guys Hans Passant and @Jens

Comment: I don't know if that will work at all. WinForms works very poorly with transparency. For transparency, better ask a new question detailing what you are trying to achieve. Best add images there as well.

Comment: @Jens Ok I've made a png transparent image. Now how to make a pciturebox transparent? (under the picturebox there is a ListView). Thanks again